Not able to read from Kafka partition when isolation-level='read_committed'
I have a transactional producer writing to Kafka topic with 1 partition.
DEBUG logs show that transactions complete without exceptions.
When this topic was read by consumer with isolation-level='read_uncommitted' everything worked fine. Then I changed isolation-level to 'read_committed' and reading stopped and consumer lag started to increase.
In consumer logs I see that every time the consumer sends 'fetch' request it receives PartitionData where lastStableOffset = logStartOffset.
Fetch READ_COMMITTED at offset 41179740 for partition topic-name-0 returned fetch data PartitionData(partitionIndex=0, errorCode=0, highWatermark=41184471, lastStableOffset=41179740, logStartOffset=41179740, divergingEpoch=EpochEndOffset(epoch=-1, endOffset=-1), currentLeader=LeaderIdAndEpoch(leaderId=-1, leaderEpoch=-1), snapshotId=SnapshotId(endOffset=-1, epoch=-1), abortedTransactions=[], preferredReadReplica=-1, records=MemoryRecords(size=0, buffer=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=0 cap=3])) 

I tried to add another partition to the topic and started to produce messages to both partitions by the same transactional producer and I saw the following:

I still can't read any messages from the first partition
Reading from the second partition works fine

All reads are performed by consumers with isolation-level='read_committed'
Would be grateful if someone can help with this issue
